# Реестр и запуск программы

Tags: windows, реестр

Нужно запустить программу с параметрами. В качестве параметров передать

```
-a "D:\path\"
```

Запуск с параметром должен быть прописать в реестре.

Мои действия:

- создал раздел Parameters
- создал мультистроковый параметер ConfigArgs
- в качестве значения передал -a "D:\path\"
- запустил тестовую программу и посмотрел параметры. Результата 0.

Answer (score 2):

А параметры обязанны передаваться через реестр? Если нет, то может это было бы проще сделать через BAT'ник или ярлык программы.

Answer (score 0):

> Запуск с параметром должен быть прописать в реестре.

что это значит? Конфигурация программы хранится в реестре и там указано что она должна запускаться с параметрами? Или параметры запуска там указаны?

Как связаны раздел Parametres, параметр ConfigArgs, который в том разделе, и запуск программы с параметром -a "D:\path\" - что программа вообще делает? Может быть проблема в алгоритме?